# On lowness of $\oplus P$

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes, polynomial-time, counting

$\oplus P$ is low for itself ($\oplus P^{\oplus P}=\oplus P$).

1. Are there other complexity classes $\mathcal D$ that satisfy $\mathcal D^{\oplus P}=\oplus P$?
2. Are there complexity classes $\mathcal C$ that satisfy $\mathcal C^{\oplus P}=\mathcal C$?

Answer (score 1):

Weak complexity classes will satisfy $\mathcal{D}^{\oplus P} = \oplus P$. For example, $P^{\oplus P} = \oplus P$.

Strong complexity classes will satisfy $\mathcal{C}^{\oplus P} = \mathcal{C}$. For example, $\mathsf{PSPACE}^{\oplus P} = \mathsf{PSPACE}$.

Comment: what is definition of weak and strong? are np and conp weak or strong?

Comment: They aren't formal terms.